# Windows 10, on my HP laptop

Tags: hard-drive

I am unable to complete a back up to my external hard drive.
I have tried several times and the details screen said the following: "Windows back up failed to get an exclusive lock on the EFI system partition (ESP). This may happen if another application is using files on the ESP. Please retry the Operation."
Details: Access is denied.
error code Ox8078011E

Why has this happened, what caused it, and how do I rectify it?
Your help and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you backing up? Windows 7 backup? Also, we don't email answers. Please take a look at the [help] and [tour] for an idea of how we do things

Answer (score 0):

You can try something that helped someone [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1e4ec1f2-fcd0-41fd-a188-55e6110786b5/windows-backup-failed-to-get-an-exclusive-lock-on-the-efi-system-partition?forum=w8itprogeneral#d25df3e4-7fa0-425b-b3a4-cb91249f650c):

> Deleting or renaming the WindowsImageBackup folder in the target
>   location and rerunning the backup